# Existe algum padrão para documentação da arquitetura de uma aplicação android?

Tags: android, arquitetura-de-software, documentação

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e só agora, no final do desenvolvimento, uma pessoa foi designada para me ajudar e me pediram para fazer um detalhamento da arquitetura para facilitar o entendimento dessa pessoa.

Estou meio perdida sobre o que devo colocar... Alguém sabe me dizer se tem algum modelo que eu possa seguir para fazer isso? Ou quais informações deveria colocar?

Grata

Comment: Existem esses modelos: MVC, MVP, MVVM...

Comment: Uma explicação sobre eles está disponível aqui: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-2f12e1c7d4db

Comment: E um exemplo deles aqui: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture

Comment: Ótimos  links @Luc

Answer (score 1):

Para documentar a arquitetura de qualquer projeto de software, o ideal é utilizar a [UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language), pois ela é uma linguagem bastante conhecida e que fornece todos os elementos para representar elementos de software. Para realizar as modelagens você pode utilizar a ferramenta [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/).

Sobre o que colocar no documento, o ideal é você ter, minimamente, modelos que ajudem a pessoa a:

- Visualizar as entidades do domínio para o qual o aplicativo foi criado e seus relacionamentos.

  - Para isso você pode criar um *Modelo Conceitual de Negócios*.
- Visualizar os componentes(ou packages) da sua aplicação e suas dependências.

  - Numa aplicação com arquitetura bem definida, cada componente fornece funcionalidades específicas para o domínio e manipula entidades específicas, por exemplo: *componente de login*, *componente de rede*, *componente de sessão* etc.